# Magento Special Price HTTP POST without "price_from" and "price_to"

Tags: magento

**Use Case:** To update a product's special price via a `HTTP` `POST` request. I can do this in the console, by going to Advanced Pricing -> Price.

**Problem:** With the HTTP POST request to the Magento endpoint `V1/products/special-price` it is required I determine when this price starts and finishes. This is a different requirement to the console and something I do not want to do.

How do I then just post to the Magento API with the `special_price` only, without requirements the available dates of this special price?

**Magento API Docs:**

*[Magento API Docs Link](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/)*

[image: V1/products/special-price]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add this code in the product object:

```
custom_attributes: [{ "attribute_code": "special_price", "value": 0.00 }]
```